# Google Sheets' dynamic data range in query function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

is it possible to have a dynamic data range when using query function in Google sheet?

What I would like to do is, using a dropbox, change the data range used in query function.

For example, I have 4 tables in 4 different sheets. On my main sheet, I want using my dropbox, perform a query on my selected table.
Is it necessary to do it with a script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google spreadsheet query to dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613423/google-spreadsheet-query-to-dropdown-list)

Comment: I'm talking about the source range

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dynamic query without using a script.

The query string can contain a reference to other cells.

[Example in Sheets.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19wjb9OPecbIEe7tLKOTC4SaRF_ssmagWyaBHrmoxerE/edit?usp=sharing)

This example has a pulldown for the data set in B2, a pulldown for the value set in B4.  The data ranges include one from another sheet.  I am using named ranges to simplify the lookup process.  Each data set n is named DataN.

You can separate out the query string from the cell with the actual query function call.  The trick is to build up a query string using INDIRECT, COLUMN, and VALUE.  I placed this in cell A10:

```
="select " & mid("ABCDEFGH",COLUMN(INDIRECT(B2)),1) & " where " & mid("ABCDEFGH",VALUE(COLUMN(INDIRECT(B2)))+1,1) & "=" & """" & B4 & """"
```

The four quotes let us place a literal quote in the query string.  The '&' character does string concatenation.
The use of MID as a way of translating the COLUMN function to a letter I got from [here](http://spreadsheetpro.net/how-to-get-letter-in-alphabet-based-on-number-in-excel-and-google-spreadsheet/).

Then your cell with the query uses the values of the data set pulldown (B2) and the value of the query string (A10) this like:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(B2),A10,1)
```